# How to execute http requests strictly one by one in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stack

So, I have an array of some values. I'd like to send these values to www.example.com. I have to send only one value per request.

I am using for this task http.request in node.js:

```
var myArr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];

function requestSender(data, callback)
  {
      var post = querystring.stringify({
        data: data
      });

      var options = {
        hostname: 'www.example.com',
        port: 80,
        path: '/upload',
        method: 'POST'
      };

      var req = https.request(options, function(res)
      {
        res.setEncoding('utf-8');
        res.on('data', function(data)
        {
          callback();
        });
      });

      req.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
      });
      req.write(post);
      req.end();
  }
```

To send requests one by one I am using function, that takes an array of functions and recursively adds next function as the callback to previous:

```
function stack(arr)
{
  var newArr = arr.slice(1);
  arr[0](function()
    {
      if (typeof newArr[0] == 'function') stack(newArr);
    });
}
```

And to compile all this staff into one, I am using the following code:

```
var functionsArr = [];
for (i in myArr)
{
  functionsArr.push(function(callback)
    {
      var value = myArr[i];
      requestSender(value, callback);
    }); 
};

stack(functionsArr);
```

But actually, this does not work: all requests are sent in 1 millisecond, and after that callbacks are listening while responses are recieved. But it should not! I have put *callback()* in http.request(options, **callback**)!! How does it happen?

So my questions are:
1) How can I send http requests strictly one by one in node.js?
2) Why does not my solution work?

Comment: What do you mean by "strictly one by one"? I took it as meaning that you don't want to start a new one until the first one has finished - but then you also wrote "as fast as possible" -- which to me indicates that you do want to send them all at once, since that would be as fast as possible.

Can you edit/clarify in what way your code is not working as you expect.

Comment: You have got the meaning of 'strictly one by one' as I wanted to. "As fast as possible" means not to use *setTimeout()* or something like that. But you are right, I should better remove "as fast as possible" thing from the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Check out the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library, specifically the mapSeries method.
2. Your callback is being called when the data is received, not when the request is finished.

Comment: Well, the problem is that my callback is called **not** when the response is recieved, but much earlier (I measure time of recieving the response with console.logging it - is this correct?)
P.S. And how to put callback on the request finish? I didnt find anything in [**docs**](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback)

Comment: callback() is called when the data is received, it is your implementation that was incorrect. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I see I'm late, but anyway:

When putting a function in a loop, or recursion, variables in closures are evaluated at the time the function is executed, not when it is created. So

```
for (i in [1, 2, 3]) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(i);
    }, 1000);
}
```

returns

```
3
3
3
```

but

```
for (i in [1, 2, 3]) {
    setTimeout(function(i) {
        return function() {
            console.log(i);
        };
    }(i), 1000);
}
```

will correctly give you

```
1
2
3
```

This is why it is generally not recommended to put function definitions in a loop.

Anyway, here is corrected code for you, note it console.logs everything in correct order:

```
var http = require('http');
var querystring = require('querystring');

var myArr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];

function requestSender(d, callback)
{
  var post = querystring.stringify({
    data: d
  });

  var options = {
    hostname: 'www.example.com',
    port: 80,
    path: '/upload',
    method: 'POST'
  };

  var req = http.request(options, function(res)
  {
    res.setEncoding('utf-8');
    res.on('data', function(data)
    {
      console.log(d);
      console.log(data);
      callback();
    });
  });

  req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
  });
  req.write(post);
  req.end();
}

function stack(arr)
{
  var newArr = arr.slice(1);
  arr[0](function(arg) {
    return function() {
      if (arg.length > 0)
        stack(arg);
    };
  }(newArr));
}

var functionsArr = [];
for (i in myArr)
{
  functionsArr.push(function(i) {
    return function(callback) {
      var value = myArr[i];
      requestSender(value, callback);
    };
  }(i));
}

stack(functionsArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
var myArr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
var counter = -1;

function function requestSender(data)
{
    var post = querystring.stringify({ data: data });
    var options =
    {
        hostname: 'www.example.com',
        port: 80,
        path: '/upload',
        method: 'POST'
    };

    var req = https.request(options, sendNextData);

    req.on('error', function(e) 
    {
        console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
    });
    req.write(post);
    req.end();
}

function sendNextData()
{
    if(++counter < myArr.length)
    {
        requestSender( myArr[ counter ] );
    }
}
sendNextData();
```